# Site Network Bar - Show Current Site Stats, CSS?

Tags: css

Currently I'm toying around with a small project and one aspect of the design is a "network bar" that will be displayed at the very top of the page and will house links to various sites that fall under the site network.

However, one functionality that I would like to incorporate is the ability to show the active site somehow.

For example:
Network Bar shows: SiteA SiteB SiteC SiteD SiteE
You're currently on: SiteC
Result throughout entire site: While in SiteC, the SiteC in the network bar is styled differently to show the status change. Whereas SiteA, B, D and E are all styled the same to show they are not the active site.

Is this possible entirely through CSS or would something like jQuery or another JavaScript snippet be needed?

Any and all help is welcome. I don't even know how I would search this further to be honest... would take sometime.

Adios!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty simple. Just add a class to the active link with an associated CSS declaration:

```
   <a href="..." class="active">My site</a>
   <a href="...">Other site</a>
```

CSS:

```
a.active {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

or:

... use an ID:

```
<a href="..." id="active">My site</a>
<a href="...">Other site</a>



a#active {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: You might want to make `active` an ID, since there will only ever be one.

Comment: Excellent! And this would be picked up throughout the site? I don't need to declare a root domain or anything?

Comment: Nope, just include it in a linked stylesheet.